# why i can not run program on my linux(qemu simulate arm32,and start a linux os)

Tags: linux, qemu

【1】, I have a linux os environment, which is based on arm32(qemu similute).

【2】, There are two file in / directory. One is "init", and one is "nesoft", but i can only run "init", and i can not run "nesoft" :

/ # ./init
This is initramfs - init !!!

/ # ./nesoft
-/bin/sh: ./nesoft: not found

【3】, The two file have dirrerence below:
zhang@zhang-Virtual-Machine:~/src/qemu/third_patry/rootfs/busybox/rootfs$ file init
init: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=08c7f187d91207660caa2db0101980a1f4b12716, notd

zhang@zhang-Virtual-Machine:~/src/qemu/third_patry/rootfs/busybox/rootfs$ file nesoft
nesoft: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 4.4.0, stripped

【4】, I have search ,so i think "LSB shared object" should run as executable file (I learn form  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472449/what-is-the-difference-between-lsb-executable-et-exec-and-lsb-shared-object )
BUT,  why it still does not run ?

【END】
Has anyone meet this before, and know why ?

Comment: do you have any OS installed in the rootfs?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference I see that second file is dynamically linked which means it requires library `.so` files to execute. I suppose it just that can't load the dependency.

Try running `ldd` (or `export LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1` before running your binary since `ldd` may not be on `busybox`) to see which library is missing.

Comment: Perhaps not this reason. Because i rebuild the "init" with "-pie" (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc init.c -o init -static -pie)  .And it is "LSB shared object" too, and it does not requires any library.  And when i put it in the qemu and run , It show the simillar error (-/bin/sh: ./init: not found) .    ---    So i think this is about the file format, but i do not know how to run it which formate is "LSB shared object," 。   -- (Sorry, my english not very good ..)

Comment: did you built the `nesoft` too yourself? are you sure it doesn't linked to a library?

Comment: no, nesoft is not my build.  I take it from somewhere.  I can make sure that "nesoft "depend on library(you are right) , but "init" does not depend on any library.  [i use "readelf -d init | grep NEEDED" to check it]

So, if the reasion is about "if it depend on library" , then why "init" also can not run,while it does not append on any library...

Comment: well doesn't that explains everything (possibly)? init doesn't depend on library and works, nesoft depends and doesn't 
Just check which library it is

Comment: So, if the reasion is about "if it depend on library" , then why "init" can not run again when i just rebuild it with "-pie", and its output format trans form "ELF 32-bit LSB executable" to "ELF 32-bit LSB shared object" .

Comment: Just building it as a LSB shared object doesn't make it depend on the external library. You should focus on the second binary and run it with `export LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1`